# Hiding fields a form in via CSS

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, jquery-plugins

So I am trying to hide some of the fields in a form. The `input type=""` section is fairly easy to hide via ID, however I can't get around to how can I edit the label class.

I did try the `:nth-child()` selector after reading a couple of posts and sites but can't seem to get it working. Here's what I did. Any suggestions of what I'm doing wrong and how I can improve?:

```css
#fc-calc-result-wraps:nth-child(2n) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="fc-calc-result-wraps" style="display: block;">
  <div class="input-group">
    <label class="control-label">Total At Retirement:</label>
    <input type="text" class="control num" id="edFV" maxlength="14" size="16" disabled="">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <label class="control-label">Contributions:</label>
    <input type="text" class="control num" id="edNumPmts" maxlength="3" size="16" disabled="">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <label class="control-label">Total Invested:</label>
    <input type="text" class="control num" id="edTotalInvested" maxlength="14" size="16" disabled="">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <label class="control-label">Interest Earned:</label>
    <input type="text" class="control num" id="edInterest" maxlength="14" size="16" disabled="">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group tail">
    <label class="control-label">Last Deposit Date:</label>
    <input type="text" class="control num" id="edFVDate" maxlength="14" size="16" disabled="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `<label>` is missing the `for=` attribute - add that correctly and use it.

Comment: Please take care to format your questions correctly. Until I edited it this originally looked like it had no HTML sample, which is vital to solving the issue.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: The format preview showed it to be working correctly but when I saw the originally question, I saw that the HTML sample wasn't available. By the time i got to editing, you did Thank you for doing that!

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you are trying to hide?  Your selector is using `id` (`#`) but you have a class and the labels are child elements, so the equivalent would be: `.fc-calc-result-wraps .input-group :nth-child(2)` which hides all the *inputs*.

Comment: @freedomn-m I am trying to hide the  "Contributions" field

Comment: @freedomn-m thank you for the clarification! Will keep this in mind next time.

Comment: So you want to hide the whole `input-group`?  In which case it's just `.fc-calc-result-wraps :nth-child(2)` - ie change to id `#` to class `.` and add a space.

Comment: Suggesting this is closed as a typo.

Comment: @freedomn-m In response to your first comment, I am editing this out of a plugin and the plugin doesnt have the for= attribute in the <label> Some of the fields that have that I am being able to edit.

In response to your last question: I want to hide just a single field. Example: Contribution

Comment: use this to hide only contributors .fc-calc-result-wraps div:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
}

Comment: @Acie_88 yes, you just need to change `#` to `.` to match on class and add a space, as above, before your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.fc-calc-result-wraps > div:nth-child(2){
  display: none;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RYwvQb